# Struct with `initializer_list` ctor inside union?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, unions

I have a struct which is POD, but for convenience, I want it to have `std::initializer_list` ctor. Default ctor, copy ctor and dtor are implicit. It seems however that using `initializer_list` ctor disqualifies the struct as POD, hence it cannot be inside a union:

```
#include<initializer_list>
struct A{
   A(const std::initializer_list<int>&);
};

union{
   A a;
} a;
```

gcc 4.6 --std=c++0x:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘<anonymous union>::._0()’
error: ‘<anonymous union>::._0()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
```

Is there away around it? Is it related to the unrestricted unions feature of c++11?

Answer (score -1):

The union itself must have an explicit ctor -- thanks to [this article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=556)):

```
union _u{
   A a;
   _u(){};
} a;
```

Comment: Well… that union constructor should also initialize `a`, so it, like `A`, has no default constructor